# POA destroyed issue in java CORBA

Tags: java, corba, orb

I am having a problem in CORBA. My server is running fine. But when I try to connect a client to the server I get this error

```
org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: POA destroyed
```

Does anybody know in which scenario do we get this error ?

Comment: I dont think there is need of any code. My only question is in which scenario we get this kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it means that the Corba ObejctReference (possessed in Client side) is not valid in Server side.
For exmple, this CorbaObject is not using Persistent policy, if the server is restarted ,then the previous Object reference will be not valid again.
To solve this problem, the client need to reobtain the object reference again.

Answer (score 1):

The exact scenarios in which this exception can be thrown are described in the [CORBA](http://www.omg.org/spec/CORBA/Current/) specification. It looks the client is invoking an object reference which points to a servant that is registered in a POA which already has been destroyed.